# how to filter children items in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i have drawer in my vuetify project, it contains drop down, and what i am working with it is accessing each drop down by the permission i have giving it and it works fine, but it filters all the contents in its drop down menu, but what i want is filtering specific children item based, how can i do that.
this is what i tried

```js
    <script>
    export default {
      data: () => ({
        permission: '',
        filtereditems: [],
        items: [
          {
            group: '/group1',
            title: 'school',
            children: [
              {
                title: 'teachers',
              },
              {
                title: 'students',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            group: '/group12',
            title: 'hostpital',
            children: [
              {
                title: 'doctor',
              },
              {
                title: 'patient',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      )},

      created () {
        this.permission = localStorage.getItem('permissions')
        const per = this.permission
        console.log(per)
        if (per === 'school') {
          this.filtereditems = this.items.filter(item => (item.title === 'school'))
          this.filtereditems = this.items.children.filter(item => (item.title === 'teacher'))
        } else if (per === 'hostpital') {
          this.filtereditems = this.items.filter(item => (item.title === 'hostpital'))
        }
      },
    }
    </script>
```

`this.filtereditems = this.items.filter(item => (item.title === 'school'))`filters fine the school drop down but
`this.filtereditems = this.items.children.filter(item => (item.title === 'teacher'))` does not filter
the children items

[image: this is the output]

[image: this is my code]

Comment: i spell it incorrectly when i posted it, but in my code teachers === teachers

Answer (score 1):

> does not filter the children items

Its more like it can't find any match

If you are looking for a phrase in string regardless where it is you can use `string.includes`

```js
item.title.includes('school')
```

--Edit

Example code to get subitems

```js
const data = {
  filtereditems: [],
  items: [{
      group: '/group1',
      title: 'school',
      children: [{
          title: 'teachers',
        },
        {
          title: 'students',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      group: '/group12',
      title: 'hostpital',
      children: [{
          title: 'doctor',
        },
        {
          title: 'patient',
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
}

data.filtereditems = data.items.find(item => item.title.includes('school'))
data.filtereditems = data.filtereditems.children.find(item => !item.title.includes('teachers'))

console.log(data.filtereditems);
```

Comment: what i want is to display school with the drop down either teacher or student  but not both..... is there any way to do that

Comment: `this.items.children` doesn't exist, @J.

Comment: i updated my post, look at the screen shots above...... when i write this line code... this.filtereditems = this.items.filter(item => Array.isArray(item.children) && item.children.map(c => c.title).includes('student'))
        it shows both student and teacher but i only want the student, how can i do that

Comment: generall what i need is to remove the teacher subitem and return only the drop down with the subitem student only.

Comment: Updated answer. here's how you can get subitems